# Ocaml vs Python - Valor de retorno da função

Tags: python, ocaml

Tenho a seguinte função escrita em ocaml

```
let rec pow((x:int), (y:int)) : int =
  if y=0 then
    1
  else
    x * pow(x,y-1)
;;
let pr = 13;;
let bs = 31;;
let getvalor num ch1 ch2 tam =
  (num * bs + int_of_char(ch1) - int_of_char(ch2) * (pow(bs, tam) mod pr)) mod pr
;;
print_int (getvalor 1 'A' 'A' 2);;
```

No print devolve -8 e implementei uma função similar em python e devolveu este valor 5 mas não estou a perceber porque os valores são diferentes nas duas saídas.

Versão em python:

```
def int_of_char(char):
  return ord(char)
def getvalor(num, ch1, ch2, bs, length, nmb2):
  return (num * bs + int_of_char(ch1) - int_of_char(ch2) * pow(bs, length, nmb2)) % nmb2

print (getvalor (1,'A','A',31,2,13))
```

Comment: Como você implementou a essa potenciação entre inteiros em OCaml?

Comment: esqueci de colocar. Ja fiz update

Comment: **Obs para quem não conhece a linguagem OCaml**, tente fazer `2 ** 3` e descobrirá que terá que fazer como ele fez ou então, se não me falhe a memória, algo assim `float_of_int 2 ** float_of_int 3|> int_of_float`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondendo sua pergunta "porque os valores são diferentes nas duas saídas?".

Essa função `pow()` que definiu em *OCaml* funciona bem com números pequenos:

```fs
# pow(2,5) ;;
- : int = 32
```

Porém na magnitude exigida em seu cálculo `bs=31` e `tam=412` o resultado ultrapassa algumas vezes o valor de `max_int`:

```fs
# max_int;;
- : int = 4611686018427387903
```

Estourando o limite numérico e retornando um valor negativo, lembrando potencia positiva de inteiros positivos o resultado é sempre positivo.

```fs
# pow(31,412) ;;
- : int = -1355500415
```

Já em python o builtin `pow()` irá retornar o valor correto pois em python virtualmente não há limite para inteiros:

```
>>> print(pow(31,412))
276069138324941945105491334106743548343721891253395677647688980210268338479815494895702857569705905259215554766122880414081265412222862455070422343941123563226292693898588710424868593004715576400093926321790564436401576623753610968630429707481035503096221766405055115180414065291029160680597540318300168902837206474368389783537831824941035360031248630200395997664286279876185196611747109383548663603552453004476274809140462798037718731829815781875721556412228287401860555521034466663555186417962593312862133585901989904028712225121222048901049818453241421257430604049981206904806269761521337270272284591644143301761
```

Em *OCaml* ao invés de realizar esses cálculos com o tipo `int` utilize algum tipo numérico de precisão arbitrária.

## Edição:

Como o AP restringiu o domínio da função, apareceu outro problema. Existe uma diferença na maneira que *OCaml* trata o operador `mod` e a maneira como *Python* trata o operador `%`.

A [definição de módulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) diz que dados dois números positivos, `a` e `b` , um módulo `b` (abreviado como `mod b` ) é o restante da [divisão euclidiana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) de `a` por `b`:

```
a = bq + r
```

Onde:

- `a` é o dividendo.
- `b` é o divisor.
- `q` é o quociente.
- `r` é o resto.

Quando dividendo e divisor são positivos tudo bem, o problema se dá quando um dos operadores é negativo e dois resultados são matematicamente possíveis.

Outro fator que influencia o resultado é pela maneira como as linguagens tratam a divisão inteira:

- Em *OCaml* a divisão inteira é arredondada para 0, o que faz com que o resultado do módulo sempre tenha o mesmo sinal que o dividendo.
- Em *Python* a divisão inteira sempre arredonda para baixo (em direção ao infinito negativo), o que faz com que o resultado do módulo sempre tenha o mesmo sinal que o divisor.

Um exemplo de divergência seria módulo da divisão de `-684` por `13`:

Em OCaml:

```fs
# -684 mod 13 ;;
- : int = -8
```

Em Python:

```
>>> -684 % 13
5
```

Então são duas soluções. Uma solução seria fazer o código *OCaml* se comportar como o código *Python*, a outra solução seria fazer o código *Python* se comportar como o código *OCaml*.

#### Primeira Alternativa: Fazer código *OCaml* se comportar como *Python*:

Para fazer o operador *OCaml* `mod` apresentar o mesmo resultado que em *Python* é preciso reimplementar o operador:

```fs
# let (mod) x y = let res = x mod y in if res < 0 then res + y else res;;
```

Ou no seu código:

```fs
let rec pow((x:int), (y:int)) : int =
  if y=0 then
    1
  else
    x * pow(x,y-1)
;;

let (mod) x y = let res = x mod y in if res < 0 then res + y else res;;

let pr = 13;;
let bs = 31;;
let getvalor num ch1 ch2 tam =
  (num * bs + int_of_char(ch1) - int_of_char(ch2) * (pow(bs, tam) mod pr)) mod pr
;;
```

Resultando:

```fs
# print_int (getvalor 1 'A' 'A' 2);;
5
```

#### Segunda Alternativa: Fazer código *Python* se comportar como *OCaml*:

Nesse caso basta substituir o operador *OCaml* `mod` pelo seu equivalente *Python* [`math.fmod()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.fmod)

```
from math import fmod

def int_of_char(char):
  return ord(char)
def getvalor(num, ch1, ch2, bs, length, nmb2):
  return int(fmod(num * bs + int_of_char(ch1) - int_of_char(ch2) * fmod(pow(bs, length), nmb2), nmb2))
```

Resultando:

```
>>>print (getvalor (1,'A','A',31,2,13)) 
-8
```

---

Usar uma ou outra solução depende de sua intenção.

Comment: alterei os valores das variáveis para ser possível representar em ambos programas mas devolve resultados diferentes

Comment: Continua com o mesmo problema `pow(31,13) ;;
- : int = -505558625` veja: https://imgur.com/a/Bu3PhpP

Comment: pow (31,2) acho que é assim

Comment: Decompus a operação em python https://repl.it/repls/DotingDapperEmulation vou fazer o mesmo em OCalm...

Comment: Em OCalm deu `a=96 b=-780 c=-684 d=-8`. Quando faz em python `(...) % nmb2` ele retorna `5` e  em OCalm `(...) mod nmb2` está retornando `-8`

Comment: Se fizer a mesma conta na [calculadora do Google](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk00Gs1eMxYb3zIPtcXkxafTwnXqfYA:1586982979231&q=-684+%25+13&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOMwf8RowS3w8sc9YSn9SWtOXmPU5OJyTsxJLs1JLMkvEpLm4nKtKChKLS7OzM8T4pXi5uLUNbMwUVBVMDTmWcSK4AAAzPiBYUkAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjS6falpOvoAhWXIbkGHQxiCmkQ6RMwJXoECAwQBA&sxsrf=ALeKk00Gs1eMxYb3zIPtcXkxafTwnXqfYA:1586982979231&biw=1366&bih=695) o resultado vai ser `5` o mesmo resultado que no python

Comment: Porém se você fizer `684 % 13`(Valor positivo) o [resultado é `8`](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk01O34e_eQtO0IuOi8qJZ2Y-u2pkrQ:1586983085246&q=684+%25+13&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOMwf8Rozi3w8sc9YSm9SWtOXmPU4OJyTsxJLs1JLMkvEpLi4nKtKChKLS7OzM8T4gFyOcwsTBRUFQyNeRaxwtkAMXpHT0cAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiU1b3YpOvoAhXlD7kGHW8NDsUQ6RMwC3oECAsQBA&biw=1366&bih=695)

Comment: Isso significa que em OCaml quando faz `mod` de um negativo o interpretador converte o negativo para positivo e depois calcula o remanescente e depois adiciona o sinal.

Comment: Para devolver o valor 5 em ocaml devo fazer o que?

Comment: @user185544 fiz uma edição na resposta espero que lhe satisfaça.

Comment: Em relação aos números de precisão arbitrária eu não estou a conseguir fazer o carregamento da biblioteca para o programa #load "nums.cma";; devolve erro de sintaxe ao tentar compilar

Comment: Ai eu não posso ajudar pois foge da minha área, já é caso de infraestrutura. É uma questão de colocar os libs no diretório certo e fazer apontamentos do OS.