# Como funciona o operador módulo (%)?

Tags: python, operadores

Tenho uma dúvida sobre operação com módulo. Por que `10 % 8` retorna `2`?

Não encontrei na documentação.

Comment: Essa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/446169/ocaml-vs-python-valor-de-retorno-da-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o/446281#446281) não trata especificamente sobre módulo, é sobre Python e OCaml mas explica o porque da diferença de resultados.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93092/70

Answer (score 3):

A documentação relevante está [aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations), e diz que o operador `%` retorna o resto da divisão do primeiro número pelo segundo ("*The % (modulo) operator yields the remainder from the division of the first argument by the second*").

Ou seja, `10 % 8` retorna `2` porque ao dividir 10 por 8, o resto da divisão é 2.

A documentação ainda menciona que "*The modulo operator always yields a result with the same sign as its second operand (or zero)*" (o operador `%` sempre retorna um valor cujo sinal é o mesmo do segundo operando (ou zero)). Por isso, quando há números negativos envolvidos no cálculo, os resultados podem ser... "estranhos":

```
print(-10 % 8) # 6
print(10 % -8) # -6
print(-10 % -8) # -2
```

A documentação menciona que o resultado de `x % y` deve ser de tal forma que `x == (x // y) * y + (x % y)` - sendo que `//` é o operador de divisão inteira, que arredonda o resultado de `x / y` usando a mesma lógica de [`floor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.floor).

Vale lembrar que também existe o [*builtin* `divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod), cujos resultados usam este operador. Basicamente, `divmod(x, y)` retorna a tupla `(x // y, x % y)`.

E no [módulo `math`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) existem ainda as funções [`remainder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.remainder) e [`fmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.fmod), que dependendo do caso podem retornar resultados diferentes de `%` (leia a documentação para entender o funcionamento de cada uma). Exemplos:

```
from math import remainder, fmod
def divs(x, y):
    print(f'\n{x} % {y} = {x % y:>15.2f}', )
    print(f'remainder({x}, {y}) = {remainder(x, y):>5.2f}')
    print(f'fmod({x}, {y}) = {fmod(x, y):>10.2f}')

divs(10, 8)
divs(-10, 8)
divs(10, -8)
divs(-10, -8)

divs(2.7, 1)
divs(-2.7, 1)
divs(2.7, -1)
divs(-2.7, -1)
```

A saída é:

```
10 % 8 =            2.00
remainder(10, 8) =  2.00
fmod(10, 8) =       2.00

-10 % 8 =            6.00
remainder(-10, 8) = -2.00
fmod(-10, 8) =      -2.00

10 % -8 =           -6.00
remainder(10, -8) =  2.00
fmod(10, -8) =       2.00

-10 % -8 =           -2.00
remainder(-10, -8) = -2.00
fmod(-10, -8) =      -2.00

2.7 % 1 =            0.70
remainder(2.7, 1) = -0.30
fmod(2.7, 1) =       0.70

-2.7 % 1 =            0.30
remainder(-2.7, 1) =  0.30
fmod(-2.7, 1) =      -0.70

2.7 % -1 =           -0.30
remainder(2.7, -1) = -0.30
fmod(2.7, -1) =       0.70

-2.7 % -1 =           -0.70
remainder(-2.7, -1) =  0.30
fmod(-2.7, -1) =      -0.70
```

Para saber mais, leia [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48347515/modulo-operation-on-a-python-negative-decimal-decimal-and-a-positive-int), [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883004/the-modulo-operation-on-negative-numbers-in-python), [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43845375/difference-between-python-3-7-math-remainder-and-modulo-operator) e [aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder).

---

Vale lembrar ainda que outras linguagens podem dar resultados diferentes quando há números negativos e/ou de ponto flutuante. Segue um exemplo em JavaScript, só para ficar em uma linguagem:

```js
console.log(10 % 8); // 2
console.log(-10 % 8); // -2
console.log(10 % -8); // 2
console.log(-10 % -8); // -2

console.log((2.7 % 1).toFixed(2)); // 0.70
console.log((-2.7 % 1).toFixed(2)); // -0.70
console.log((2.7 % -1).toFixed(2)); // 0.70
console.log((-2.7 % -1).toFixed(2)); // -0.70
```

Repare que nem todos os resultados são iguais ao Python. Isso porque a definição de "resto da divisão" é meio "ingênua e limitada". Ela funciona muito bem para números positivos, mas quando há números negativos envolvidos, tudo se complica. Existem variantes desta definição, que fazem com que o sinal do resultado acabe sendo o mesmo do dividendo ou do divisor (e que são explicadas [neste artigo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), no qual há inclusive uma tabela comparativa entre várias linguagens, mostrando como cada uma implementa o `%`).

Comment: Considero um erro de documentação misturar o conceito de módulo com resto de divisão (e várias linguagens fazem isso). Módulo é "aritmética de relógio", cíclica, resto é outra coisa. Nos negativos faz toda diferença, como vc mencionou. E isso tem implicações em uma série de aplicações práticas.