# Problemas com append incremetando até o infinito em Python

Tags: python, array, while, append

Estou fazendo um programa que faz varredura de 35 bits em um equipamento, guardo os bits de referência em um array. A lógica para saber se algum bit mudou desde a última leitura, sempre salva o resultado anterior e compara com o atual com o atual. Nessa parte, tudo funciona como o esperado.

```
from pyModbusTCP.client import ModbusClient
import time

SERVER_HOST = "10.0.0.66"
SERVER_PORT = 555

c = ModbusClient()
c.host(SERVER_HOST)
c.port(SERVER_PORT)

endereco = 0
bit = []
bit.clear()

while True:
    
    if not c.is_open():
        if not c.open():
            print("não é possível conectar em "+SERVER_HOST+":"+str(SERVER_PORT))    

    if c.is_open():

        bit_atual = c.read_coils(endereco, 1)
        bit.append(bit_atual)
 
        if bit_atual:
            if  bit_atual != bit[endereco]:
                print("bit[" + str(endereco)+"] = " + str(bit_atual)+ " -> MUDEI ")
                
            else:
                print("bit[" + str(endereco)+"] = " + str(bit_atual))
            
                  
        bit[endereco] = bit_atual
        endereco = endereco + 1
    
        if endereco == 35: 
            endereco = 0
            time.sleep(2)
            print("  ")
            print("  ")
```

O problema que estou tendo é que ao usar o "append" para adicionar elementos na array ele sempre adiciona mais 35 linhas a cada loop do while, sendo eu só preciso das 35 primeiras linhas.

Se eu deixo rodando um tempo e faço um len(bit) o valor já está enorme, em algum momento ele acaba estourando o limite.

Pensei usar um bit.clear() no final do loop de while, mas não posso pois eu sempre uso a leitura anterior para comparar com a atual.

Tentei trocar o

```
bit.append(bit_atual)
```

por

```
bit.append[endereco]=bit_atual
```

Pois acredito que ele vá sempre substituir o valor com o seu endereço, mas ele retorna com o erro:

```
bit[endereco]=bit_atual
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Será alguém puder me dar uma luz? Existe uma forma de limitar um append? ou alguma outra forma?
Obrigado

*bit_atual são valores booleanos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como o `append` é chamado dentro de um *loop* infinito, é claro que a lista vai crescer indefinidamente.

Se a ideia é que ela tenha no máximo 35 elementos, acho que o melhor é criá-la já com este tamanho, aí no *loop* você só se preocupa em verificar a posição relativa ao endereço. Algo assim:

```
tamanho_maximo = 35
endereco = 0
# cria a lista com 35 posições (inicialmente com o valor None)
bit = [None] * tamanho_maximo

while True:
    if not c.is_open():
        if not c.open():
            print(f"não é possível conectar em {SERVER_HOST}:{SERVER_PORT}")    

    if c.is_open():
        bit_atual = c.read_coils(endereco, 1)
        if bit_atual:
            if bit[endereco] is not None and bit_atual != bit[endereco]:
                print(f"bit[{endereco}] = {bit_atual} -> MUDEI ")
            else:
                print(f"bit[{endereco}] = {bit_atual}")

        bit[endereco] = bit_atual
        if endereco == tamanho_maximo - 1:
            time.sleep(2)
            print("  \n  ")
        endereco = (endereco + 1) % tamanho_maximo
```

Assim, a lista começa com 35 valores iguais a [`None`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html?highlight=none#None). Depois, basta ver se o valor do bit atual não é `None` (pois o `None` indica que ele ainda não foi setado), e caso não seja, veja se ele mudou.

Também mudei outras coisas: usei [*f-string*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) em vez de concatenar strings (disponível a partir do Python 3.6), e usei o operador `%` ([resto da divisão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/468522/112052)) para incrementar o valor de `endereco`, assim ele já volta para zero quando atingir o tamanho máximo.

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!