# Dado um número, obter o dígito das dezenas

Tags: python, matemática

Escreva uma função que recebe um número inteiro de até três dígitos e retorna a
quantidade de dezenas desse número. Não faça transformações de tipos.

- Entrada: (2) ; Saída: 0
- Entrada: (85) ; Saída: 8
- Entrada: (321) ; Saída: 2

Código:

```
def questao6(n):
    result = n // 10
    print(result)
```

No caso 3, o código me retorna 32 e não 2. Tem como eu resolver essa questão sem usar nada além de operadores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com 321, o resultado dá 32 porque você só divide o número por 10 - e o [operador](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) `//` faz a "divisão inteira", ou seja, arredonda o resultado. E 321 dividido por 10 dá 32.

O que falta é pegar o último dígito do resultado da divisão, que você pode obter usando o resto da divisão por 10 (com o [operador `%`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/468522/112052)):

```
def questao6(n):
    result = (n // 10) % 10
    print(result)
```

Se bem que, se for só para imprimir, nem precisa da variável `result`:

```
def questao6(n):
    print((n // 10) % 10)
```

---

Mas eu faria a função retornar o valor, e aí quem a chamou que decide o que fazer (podendo, inclusive, imprimir):

```
def dezena(n): # dando um nome melhor para a função
    return (n // 10) % 10

for i in [2, 85, 321]: # testando com vários números
    print(i, dezena(i))
```

---

<sup>E só para ser pedante, o que está sendo pedido na verdade é o dígito correspondente à dezena. Porque se fosse realmente a "*quantidade de dezenas*", então `32` estaria certo, afinal 321 "tem" de fato 32 dezenas :-)</sup>

Comment: muito obrigado!! estou restrito a fazer apenas com os operadores.

Answer (score -2):

```
 def questao6(n):
     result = ( n % 100 ) // 10
     print(result)
```

Comment: Irá obter apenas o valor da dezena.