# Problemas com a escolha da opção 'papel' num programa que 'joga' jokenpo comigo

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um programa que "jogue" jokenpo comigo.

As opções 'pedra' e 'tesoura' estão funcionando. Entretanto, quando entro com a opção 'papel' e a máquina escolhe a opção 'tesoura', o programa diz que eu venci.

Eu li código novamente e não consigo encontrar o erro. Segue o código:

```
import random
e1: str = 'pedra'
e2: str = 'papel'
e3: str = 'tesoura'
lista = [e1, e2, e3]
esc_maquina = random.choice(lista)
minha_esc = str(input('Minha escolha é: '))
if minha_esc == esc_maquina:
    print('Houve empate! Sua escolha foi {} e da máquina também foi {}.'.format(minha_esc, esc_maquina))
    print('Pressione Shift+F10 e tente novamente!')
elif minha_esc != esc_maquina:
        if minha_esc == e1 and esc_maquina == e2 or esc_maquina == e3:   # Pedra
            if esc_maquina == e2:
                print('Você perdeu! A máquina escolheu {}.'.format(e2))
                print('Para tentar novamente, pressione Shift+F10')
            elif esc_maquina == e3:
                print('Você venceu! A máquina escolheu {}.'.format(e3))
                print('Para tentar novamente, pressione Shift+F10')
        elif minha_esc == e2 and esc_maquina == e1 or esc_maquina == e3:   # Papel
            if esc_maquina == e1:
                print('Você venceu! A máquina escolheu {}.'.format(e1))
                print('Para tentar novamente, pressione Shift+F10')
            elif esc_maquina == e3:
                print('Você perdeu! A máquina escolheu {}.'.format(e3))
                print('Para tentar novamente, pressione Shift+F10')
        elif minha_esc == e3 and esc_maquina == e1 or esc_maquina == e2:   # Tesoura
            if esc_maquina == e1:
                print('Você perdeu! A máquina escolheu {}.'.format(e1))
                print('Para tentar novamente, pressione Shift+F10')
            elif esc_maquina == e2:
                print('Você venceu! A máquina escolheu {}.'.format(e2))
                print('Para tentar novamente, pressione Shift+F10')
else:
    print('Não há nada aqui. Pressione Shift+F10 e volte ao começo!')
```

Answer (score 1):

Sua lista ficou `['pedra', 'papel', 'tesoura']`. Ou seja, o primeiro elemento perde do segundo, o segundo perde do terceiro e o terceiro perde do primeiro. Então bastaria pegar a posição de cada uma das opções e compará-las. Para isso podemos usar o método `index` da lista.

Se as opções são iguais, deu empate. Se a posição que você escolheu é anterior à posição que o computador escolheu, você perdeu. Senão, você ganhou. Ou seja:

```py
# verifica se eu ganhei do computador
def resultado(opcoes, eu, comp):
    if eu == comp: # se forem iguais, empatou
        return 'empate'
    # busca a posição de cada um
    indice_eu = opcoes.index(eu)
    indice_comp = opcoes.index(comp)
    if (indice_eu + 1) % len(opcoes) == indice_comp:
        return 'perdi'
    return 'ganhei'
```

A ideia é ver se a posição do computador é imediatamente depois da minha. Mas eu também uso o [operador `%`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/468522/112052) (resto da divisão) para voltar à primeira posição, caso ela seja a terceira.

Testando:

```py
opcoes = ['pedra', 'papel', 'tesoura']
for eu in opcoes:
    for comp in opcoes:
        print(f'eu={eu}, comp={comp}, resultado={resultado(opcoes, eu, comp)}')
```

Saída:

```
eu=pedra, comp=pedra, resultado=empate
eu=pedra, comp=papel, resultado=perdi
eu=pedra, comp=tesoura, resultado=ganhei
eu=papel, comp=pedra, resultado=ganhei
eu=papel, comp=papel, resultado=empate
eu=papel, comp=tesoura, resultado=perdi
eu=tesoura, comp=pedra, resultado=perdi
eu=tesoura, comp=papel, resultado=ganhei
eu=tesoura, comp=tesoura, resultado=empate
```

---

Claro que assim eu tenho que ter certeza que minha escolha está na lista, então teria que fazer algo do tipo:

```py
while True:
    minha_escolha = input('Minha escolha é: ')
    if minha_escolha in opcoes: # escolha está na lista
        break # interrompe o while
    else:
        print(f'As escolhas válidas são: {", ".join(opcoes)}')
```

Ou seja, se digitar uma escolha que não está na lista, pede que digite novamente. Note também que [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) já retorna uma string, então fazer `str(input())` é redundante e desnecessário.

Assim eu garanto que só digitei um elemento que com certeza existe na lista, e assim `index` sempre retornará um índice válido. Para a escolha do computador não precisa, pois você usa `random.choice` que garantidamente pega um elemento que existe nela. Claro que se a lista fosse maior, o mais eficiente seria trabalhar diretamente com os índices (em vez de buscá-los toda hora), mas para uma lista com apenas 3 elementos não deve fazer diferença.

E claro que, em vez de retornar "ganhei" ou "perdi", você pode fazer quaisquer ações que desejar (como imprimir alguma mensagem específica, etc). Só que, como `return` encerra a execução da função, se for para retirá-lo você deve alterar um pouco. Ex:

```py
def resultado(opcoes, eu, comp):
    if eu == comp:
        print(f'Empate, ambos escolheram {eu}')
    else:
        indice_eu = opcoes.index(eu)
        indice_comp = opcoes.index(comp)
        if (indice_eu + 1) % len(opcoes) == indice_comp:
            msg = 'Você perdeu!'
        else:
            msg = 'Você venceu!'
        print(f'{msg} A máquina escolheu {comp} e você escolheu {eu}')
```