# jogo da velha em python as vezes não mostra resultado

Tags: python, python-3.x

fiz um programa de jogo da velha em python 3 mas o problema é que quando eu escolho uma opção não mostra nada as vezes mas certa parte do tempo funciona dizendo se ganhei ou perdi
código:

```
insira o código aqui
import random

pedra = 'Pedra'
papel = 'Papel'
tesoura = 'Tesoura'

jogador = str(input('Pedra, papel ou tesoura? Fale: ')).capitalize()

if jogador.capitalize() == random.choice([pedra, papel, tesoura]).capitalize():
    print('Deu empate!')
elif jogador.capitalize() == pedra and  random.choice([pedra, papel, tesoura]) == tesoura:
    print('Você venceu! Pedra ganha de tesoura.')
elif jogador.capitalize() == papel and random.choice([pedra, papel, tesoura]) == pedra:
    print('Você venceu! Papel ganha de pedra.')
elif jogador.capitalize() == tesoura and random.choice([pedra, papel, tesoura]) == papel:
    print('Você venceu! Tesoura ganha de papel.')
elif jogador.capitalize() == pedra and random.choice([pedra, papel, tesoura]) == papel:
    print('Você perdeu! Papel ganha de tesoura.')
elif jogador.capitalize() == papel and random.choice([pedra, papel, tesoura]) == tesoura:
    print('Você perdeu! Tesoura ganha de papel.')
elif jogador.capitalize() == tesoura and random.choice([pedra, papel, tesoura]) == pedra:
    print('Você perdeu! Pedra ganha de tesoura.')
else:
    print('As vezes o programa não escolhe algum então dá nisso malz kkkk')
```

Comment: Tenta fazer: abaixo da linha `jogador =...` coloque `sorteio = random.choice(....`. Finalmente, para cada `if` use `if ..... == sorteio`.

Comment: Só pra constar, esse não é o jogo da velha :-) De qualquer forma, dê uma olhada aqui que já tem praticamente "pronto":  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/519193/112052 (inclusive, com uma resposta que mostra um jeito melhor de verificar o resultado)

Comment: Esse não é o [jogo da velha](https://www.google.com/search?q=jogo+da+velha&oq=jogo+da+velha&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

Toda vez que voce verifica se a sua opção bate com `random.choice([pedra, papel, tesoura]).capitalize():` voce esta criando um novo valor para a opção do sistema.

Cria uma variável antes do seus `if`s e usa ela para compara com sua resposta:

`selecaoComputador = random.choice([pedra, papel, tesoura]).capitalize():`

depois somente faca assim:

```
if jogador.capitalize() == selecaoComputador:
    print('Deu empate!')
elif jogador.capitalize() == pedra and  selecaoComputador == tesoura:
    print('Você venceu! Pedra ganha de tesoura.')
elif jogador.capitalize() == papel and selecaoComputador == pedra:
    print('Você venceu! Papel ganha de pedra.')
elif jogador.capitalize() == tesoura and selecaoComputador == papel:
    print('Você venceu! Tesoura ganha de papel.')
elif jogador.capitalize() == pedra and selecaoComputador == papel:
    print('Você perdeu! Papel ganha de tesoura.')
elif jogador.capitalize() == papel and selecaoComputador == tesoura:
    print('Você perdeu! Tesoura ganha de papel.')
elif jogador.capitalize() == tesoura and selecaoComputador == pedra:
    print('Você perdeu! Pedra ganha de tesoura.')
else:
    print('nao deve chegar aqui')
```