# Qual a diferença do operador de resto (%) em Python e Rust?

Tags: python, operadores, rust

Escrevendo um pequeno programa em Rust, notei que os resultados do operador `%` são diferentes do que obtenho no Python para números negativos. Por exemplo, em Python `-4 % 26` retorna 22, mas em Rust:

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", (-4 % 26));
}
```

Retorna -4!

Eu olhei a [documentação](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/appendix-02-operators.html) dos operadores de Rust e, ao que parece, o operador `%` é de *remainder* mesmo, assim como no Python.

Por que a diferença?

**P.S:** Para contexto, nessa parte do código estou forçando o número de interesse a ter um valor entre 0 e 25. No Python a estratégia de usar o *remainder* funciona, mas no Rust, não.

Comment: A lógica do Python está explicada [aqui](/q/468522/112052). No Rust eu não sei, mas *me parece* seguir a [mesma ideia do JavaScript](/a/93099/112052). Lembrando que *remainder* e *módulo* [são 2 conceitos diferentes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20638659), e para números positivos costumam se confundir pois os resultados são iguais (muitas linguagens, inclusive, também confundem os nomes, dizem que implementam um quando na verdade é outro). Outro link relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/446169/112052

Comment: A diferença é que, em Python, o `%` não é _remainder_, mas sim _modulo_. Em Rust, o `%` é, de fato, _remainder_. As definições de `mod` e `rem` são diferentes, de modo que surge essa discrepância.

Comment: Obrigado pelos esclarecimentos, pessoal. Para quem vir parar aqui pelo mesmo motivo, saiba que é possível obter o módulo no Rust usando `(-4).rem_euclid(26)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A premissa básica é que, embora o símbolo seja o mesmo, o significado pode ser diferente.

| Operador | Linguagem | Semântica |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `%` | Rust | [*Remainder*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/appendix-02-operators.html) |
| `%` | Python | [*Modulus*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) |

Essa diferença ocorre entre várias outras linguagens de programação também. Há linguagens que optam por nomes como `rem` e `mod`, o que remove a ambiguidade trazida pelo `%`.

Existem [várias formas de se definir a “Operação Módulo” em computadores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Variants_of_the_definition). A diferença surge ao realizar a computação do quociente. As duas mais comuns são:

```
mod(a, b) = a - b * floor(a / b)
rem(a, b) = a - b * trunc(a / b)
```

Perceba que o `mod` irá arredondar o resultado da divisão para baixo. O `rem`, contudo, arredonda o número tendendo ao zero. Veja a diferença entre números negativos e positivos em `1.5` e `-1.5`:

```
 floor(1.5) =  1, trunc( 1.5) =  1
floor(-1.5) = -2, trunc(-1.5) = -1
```

Então, no caso de um dos dois argumentos fornecidos for menor que zero, essas definições abrem margem para diferença entre seus respectivos resultados.

#### Definição matemática

A [Wikipedia define “Operação Módulo“](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) assim:

> Dados dois números positivos, `a` e `n`, `a modulo n` é o resto da divisão Euclidiana de `a` por `n`, onde `a` é o dividendo e `n` o divisor.
>
> Quando exatamente um de `a` ou `n` é negativo, a definição *naïve* falha e as linguagens de programação diferem na forma como esses valores são definidos.
>
> Matematicamente, o resultado da operação módulo é uma [classe de equivalência](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Congruence_classes) e qualquer membro dessa classe pode ser escolhido como representante. Comumente, contudo, o menor resto positivo é escolhido.

Como outras convenções de como escolher esse representante são possíveis, surge a diferença no momento de se implementar um algoritmo para determinar o resto da divisão Euclidiana. E esse algoritmo irá depender da linguagem de programação, já que não há consenso — todos são válidos de acordo com a identidade matemática. Tanto `mod` como `rem` são válidos, embora produzam resultados diferentes.

Veja todas as [variações aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Variants_of_the_definition) e as [implementações mais comuns por linguagem de programação](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#In_programming_languages).

#### Diferenças em aplicações

Pode-se entender `mod` como uma operação que mapeia um número qualquer a um conjunto bem definido de valores. Veja a aplicação `x mod 3` para `x` de -5 até 5:

```
-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5       (valores de x)
 1,  2,  0,  1,  2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2       (resultados para `x mod 3`)
```

Veja que o resultado é cíclico e encontra-se no conjunto inteiro `[0, 3[`.

Contudo, ao utilizar `rem`, temos um resultado diferente:

```
-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5       (valores de x)
-2, -1,  0, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2       (resultados para `x rem 3`)
```

Veja que, para `rem`, o conjunto de resultados possíveis depende do sinal dos operandos, o que remove o “rigor cíclico” que existe em `mod`.

A maioria das linguagens oferecem tanto `rem` quanto `mod` (não necessariamente com esses nomes), já que, como os resultados variam, o uso também pode ser impactado. Em algumas situações, somente `mod` se encaixa. Em outras, somente `rem` resolverá. Quando os operandos passados tiverem, garantidamente, o mesmo sinal, não há diferença.